# MATLAB: Changing the font of of XTickLabel, YTickLabel, etc

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB one can change the font name of things such as `ylabel`, `xlabel`, `title`, etc. of a plot, e.g.

```
ylabel(y_string, 'FontName', 'Palatino')
```

However, is it possible to change the font of the XTicks, YTicks, etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had fights with tick fonts before. I think they generally use the axes font, in which case something like:

```
set(gca, 'FontName', 'Palatino');
```

should work. If this is unsuccessful, you could try [Format Tick Labels](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15986) from the file exchange. It replaces the ticks with text objects, so the formatting can be completely customised as with any text object (I seem to remember having a look at it a while ago; you might need to hack around in the code to choose the font).

Comment: aha, but my solution wouldn't give a 'String constant not terminated properly' error ;-)

Comment: Also, the Format Tick Labels program does not handle semilog or loglog plots.

Answer (score 2):

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{labelList}, 'FontSize',8,'FontName','Times')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the handle of the current axes using the `gca` command:

```
set(gca, 'FontName', 'Palatino');
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: [How to change font size of x axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711606/how-to-change-font-size-of-x-axis)

Here's the answer from that post, thanks to user Marc Manzano. Note that it changes both the font (which you asked for) and the font size (which is how I found this thread):

```matlab
plot(X)
set(gca, 'FontName', 'Arial')
set(gca, 'FontSize', 12)
ylabel('Label Y axis')
xlabel('Label X axis')
```

The point that is important is that you do the `set()` commands BEFORE the `ylabel` and `xlabel` commands. I'm not sure *exactly* why/how that works, but it worked for me on a log-log plot.