# How to change font size of x axis?

Tags: matlab, axis, figure

Is there any way to change the font size property of x axis in MATLAB for a figure? I need to change the size of the values in x axis (not the title, that one could modify with `xlabel` property). I have the next piece of code:

```
%% Some figure properties:
width=15;height=20;alw=0.75;

%% Figure:
for i=1:8
      figure;set(gcf,'color','white');
      pos=get(gcf, 'Position');
      set(gcf, 'Position', [pos(1) pos(2) width*100, height*100]);
      set(gca, 'LineWidth', alw);axis off;
      axes('position',[0.06 0.08 0.87 0.38])
      plot(0:24,s(i).obs(:,1),'linewidth',2,'color','b');hold on;
      plot(0:24,s(i).sim(:,1)-273.15,'linewidth',2,'color','r');
      legend('Obs','Sim','location','northeastoutside');
      set(gca,'xtick',0:24,'xticklabel',0:24);
      set(gca,'ytick',2:2:28,'yticklabel',2:2:28);
      xlabel('Hour');ylabel('[°C]');axis([0 24 2 28]);grid on;
      axes('position',[0.06 0.53 0.87 0.38]);
      plot(s(i).time.obs,s(i).serie.obs,'b');hold on;
      plot(s(i).time.sim,s(i).serie.sim-273.15,'r');
      datetick('x','myy');axis tight;grid on;
      legend('Obs','Sim','location','northeastoutside');
      title([s(i).name ', porcNaN: ' num2str(roundn(s(i).rnan,-1)) ...
          '%, period: '  datestr(s(i).period(1,:),20) ' - '...
           datestr(s(i).period(2,:),20)],'fontsize',12);
      ylabel('[°C]');set(gca,'fontsize',8)
      image_name=['temp_sup_' s(i).name];
      print(image_name,'-dpng','-r600')
end
```

"s" is a struct. The problem is the values in the x axis of the second plot (the figure above), datetick put all months and years values, I need this information (each one month), but they're very close together. I know the "fontsize" property, but this property change the font size in the two axis (x and y), and I need only change the x axis.

Comment: Are you trying to change the size of the tick labels on the axis? Your code is way more complicated than is needed for this....

Answer (score 11):

I always do it in the following way:

```
plot(X)
set(gca, 'FontName', 'Arial')
set(gca, 'FontSize', 12)
ylabel('Label Y axis')
xlabel('Label X axis')
```

In this way, the axis and the label will have the requested font and size. It is important to put `'xlabel'` and `'ylabel'` after the `'set'`. The order in this case matters.

There is other way to set the fonts for the xlabel, ylable, legend, plot as below; it may complement the upper answer:

```
% Define values
linewidthnumber = 2;
legendfontsize = 12;
labelfontsize = 12;
axisfontsize = 12;
custom_plot_handle_name = plot(x);
custom_legend_handle_name = legend();
custom_x_label_name = xlabel();
custom_y_label_name = ylabel();

% Set the parameters now to the given values
set(h, 'Linewidth', linewidthnumber);
set(custom_legen_handle_name,'FontSize', legendfontsize);
set(custom_x_label_name, 'FontSize', labelfontsize);
set(custom_y_label_name, 'FontSize', labelfontsize);
set(gca, 'FontSize', axisfontsize);
```

Comment: AWESOME. Just FYI: unlike some others' solutions, this method DOES work for semilog and loglog plots. I'd guess it works generally.